# JFrog remote repository name without the project key prefix

Tags: artifactory

How to create a JFrog remote repository with a name that doesn't include the project key prefix?

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost sure that it is impossible to create a repository name in a project environment, without the project key prefix.

However, please consider the following workaround:

1. Create a [remote repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Remote+Repositories) in your project named `<proj>-awesome-repo`.
2. Create a [virtual repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-VirtualRepositories) in the default space (without project associated) named `awesome-repo`. Include the remote repository `proj-remote-repo` in the virtual repository.
3. Use `awesome-repo` as the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin permissions you can directly create a repository without any Project key as a prefix and then you can add the created repository to that Specific Project.

If you are not an admin, then we dont have an option to create a local|remote repo without Project prefix. The only way is to associate this with any virtual repi.